# Can anyone tell me what font this is?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

Can someone please help me identify this font?

[image: font picture]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like **[ITC Franklin Gothic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/franklin-gothic/)** to my eye. Or something very close.

[image: Look harder next time]

Comment: Original seems a tiny bit bolder (probably Photoshop rendering option), but seems like a match to me!

Comment: Agreed on the rendering discrepancy. My image is directly from MyFonts; I'm sure Pshop would be different. There's an off chance that it comes from the MUCH more expensive (and expansive) [Font Bureau version](http://www.fontbureau.com/fonts/ITCFranklin/styles/).

Comment: plainclothes is right .. it is ITC Franklin Gothic. the bowl on the lowercase g and the a and the e are indicative of that typeface.

Answer (score 1):

Looks closer to Medium to me -- to add to Plainclothes answer.
[image]

Comment: Too heavy. It's the normal weight. Just a rendering discrepancy.